# ISAPI Authentication IIS6

Tags: security, iis, isapi

I want to secure some folders/directories on my website which is running under IIS6, but I don't want to enter the users in Active Directory or make them windows users in any way.  I have the users/passwords in a database currently.  In the past I had to purchase special ISAPI filters/applications in order to create password protected directories that could look up users/pass in DB or a flat-file (like an .htaccess type thing)... something like http://www.flicks.com/flicks/authx.htm or http://www.iistools.com/en/iispassword.html or http://www.dotnetprotect.com/

assuming I don't want to do any custom development... what are my options for making this work in IIS6?   Are there any free/open-source options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I think I have a slightly better understanding of what you're looking for now.

Here's a couple more options to consider:

**Change to Apache for Win32**

This would solve your problem... for free... but only you can assess if it's worth the effort to make the move.

**ISAPI Rewrite**

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

I'm not positive this will work for you... but I seem to recall others being able to do .htaccess stuff with it.  You'll have to research this one a bit.

**IISPassword**

http://www.iistools.com/en/iispassword.html

Probably too expensive for you.

The free version will allow up to 3 users I think.  IISPassword will allow you to protect your site without using system user accounts.

I'm not sure if any solution is REALLY going to help you get away from development... but this should be close.

Comment: this board doesn't seem to be as hoppin as StackOverflow... but I'm going with IISPassword for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind, StackOverflow is a bit older... 271,000+ questions vs the 12,000+ here. Give us some time. We'll get there eventually. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually going to recommend authx by flicks software but I see you've already mentioned it.

That's probably the EASIEST way to do it... but here's another example you may wish to look into:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210323190338/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/021600-1.shtml)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks... but trying not to do any custom development if I dont have to.  waiting to see if anyone has any free/open-source options